# Issue outputting text to textBox (WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

It's my first time using winforms. I'm having some issues.

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "FORM1";
            textBox1.AppendText("SOME TEXT");
        }
    }
```

I've tried this. My textbox is set to fill so it fills up the whole form. I set the multi-line propery to true and dock property to fill.

From what I can try as a first time WinForms user, the Form1_Load should run as soon as the form is created. I've tried some various ways to print text, nothing works. I noticed visual studios says "0 references" next to my function. I'm not sure what this means, maybe part of my issue? Please help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the question? In my case text box fills up correctly when using your code. What are you trying to achieve with `text changed` event ?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Nothing is happening. No text it ever being output to my textbox! I don't understand. If it's working for you I might try recreating project. Not sure what that'll do for me though.

Comment: It looks like your form load event is not registered. Open designer, select the form and go to properties window (Ctrl+W, P). Here choose events, and look for `Load` event. Copy `Form1_Load1` and paste at the box next to event name

Comment: It sounds like you just typed out that event handler, but did not hook subscribe it to the `Form1.Load` event. In the `Form1()` constructor, try adding the line: `this.Load += Form1_Load;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having 0 references to method means that it's never used in code. So your issue is that you defined method, which looks like should be executed on form load event, but it's just the definition. I suggest that you copy body of your method to clipboard, go to design page of your form, on the right side, you can browse events, that form generates, find `Load` event, double-click it, Visual Studio should generate code with empty method definition, paste there your code.

When you right-click your method name and click `Find all references` you should get something like this at the bottom:

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU. I don't understand though, I typed the EXACT same thing myself in the same file, I commented out my function before hand to compare. Then I used your method. They are literally identical. Yet when I did it myself I get 0 references, but when I do it your way I get the reference immediately. I actually just spent an hour trying to figure this out, looking at references & seeing my code looked fine. 

Is there anyway you could explain why this happened? I was under the impression you could code anything manually in the winforms files, OR use your method.

Comment: Visual Studio automatically generates all code necessary for you. When you typed manually your method you most probably forgot to add it to your eventhandler: `this.Load += new System.EventHandler...` on picture I attached.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked following things are done in properties:

Go to Form1->Properties window and check for events. 
Now check for Load event and it should be attached to your Form1_Load method.

[image]